# How do I rewrite part of a multistring from a text file without deleting whole row or rewriting entire multistring?

Tags: python, text

What I want to be able to do is get a user input of which candidate they would like to modify their status of and change it from either IN PROCESS to CLOSED or vice versa without damaging the rest of their information.

```
elif test_number3 == 3:
            files = open("CanidateForm.txt", "w")
            print(files.read())

            num = input("Which candidates status do you want to change?(choose a number)\n")
            number = int(num)

            #if number is chosen between 1 to 17 change only the status of the candidate picked from IN PROCESS to CLOSED


            continue
```

Currently, the text file looks like this but with more candidates

```
Shawez Ahmed, Senior Business Analyst, 2020-02-21, , 2020-03-04, , , IN PROCESS, Client Interview, $100k, All Docs. OK, , 2020-03-04
```

Comment: You could store your data in a dictionary and then use json.loads to read it from the file and json.dumps to write it back. 
It will also be Faster for you to lookup records from a dict.

Comment: I would probably use a list of lists for the text file and use a dictionary to change the status. Can it be assumed that all lines in the text document are standardized?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your text file has data in CSV format. Python's [CSV library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) will be useful for you. It has a [reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) and a [writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) that you can use to solve this exact problem